# Mongo query for value in an object with any key

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

Supposing we have documents in a Mongo collection with the following format:

```
{
    "_id" : "5fb3c5ce9997c61e15a9108c",
    "stages" : {
          "stage1" : {
              "type" : "RandomType"
          },
          "stage2" : {
              "type" : "RandomType2"
          },
          "arbitaryStage" : {
              "type" : "RandomType3"
          },
          // Possibly many other stages
    },
    // Fields omitted
}
```

How can I query a collection of such documents where any `stages.X.type` is equal to a predefined value? My application doesn't know what X is and doesn't care about it, it should only know that the type of at least one of the stages is equal to a given value. I am trying to do that in Morphia however plain JS would guide me if that's possible to do with the given data format.

For reference the Class from which this entity is originated from is the following

```
@Entity(value = "stages_collection", noClassnameStored = true)
public class StackOverflowQ {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    @Embedded
    private Map<String, Stage> stages;
    // Rest of fields/setters/getters omitted
}

public class Stage {
    private String type;
    // Rest of fields/setters/getters omitted
}
```

Comment: Using `mongo` shell: You can try using Aggregation query with the `$objectToArray` operator applied on the `stages` embedded-document. Then follow it with a `$match` stage to match the `stages.v.type`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you employ a blanket check, if the system cannot pick the right field then basically the best we can do is search the whole collection, even if you find someway to do it it won't be a very efficient.

A simple change in schema would be better when you expect random fields in the data. In your case.

```
{
 stageName : "Stage 1",
 type : "RandomType" 
}
```

You will be able to utilise indexes properly here as well when you scale and the flexibility remains in your hands for future additions. No need to change things in the code when a new stage is required.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option I have in this case  although it's ideal.